# Modified Chi-squared random variable and its distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, chi-squared

I know that if a random variable is defined like this,

$\Delta_{N}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}^{2}$

where, $Z_{i}\sim N(0,1)$. Then $\Delta_{N}$ is called chi-squared random variable of N degree(s) of freedom.

Now my question is, let us define a new random variable,

$\Delta_{N}^{'}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_{i}Z_{i}^{2}$

where $\alpha_{i}$'s are constant coefficients.

Question is what type of distribution they will follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a Gamma distribution.

By looking at the moment generating function of $Y_i=\alpha_iZ_i^2$, you will see that

$$
M_{Y_i}(t) = (1-2\alpha_it)^{\frac{N}{2}}
$$

Which demonstrates that $Y_i\sim Gamma(2\alpha_i,\frac{N}{2})$.  We know that the sum of Gamma distributions with the same second parameter is itself a Gamma where the first parameter of the sum is the sum of the first parameters of the individuals.

$$
\Delta'_N\sim Gamma(\sum_{i=1}^N2\alpha_i,\frac{N}{2})
$$

Comment: Hi.... thank you for valuable answer. If you don't mine can you look at this question also - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615040/about-l2-error-distribution-and-its-strange-oscillatory-behaviour

Comment: @aranyak Thanks, I'll take a look. If you could please mark this as correct answer, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since definition of chi-square is been concerted through that definition, hence $\Delta_{N}^{'}$ will not obey chi-square distribution. That is technically correct answer according to me. But on the same time since $\alpha_{i}$'s are constant coefficients, hence qualitative characteristics of density functions of $\Delta_{N}^{'}$ will be same as chi-square density function as DOF changes. Have a look at density functions of `pure' chi-square RV -

\

\

[image: Density functions of chi-squared RV]
\

\

Reason why I think so is that, if someone questions that why for DOF=1 density function peaks at 0? Answer is, if apply transformation formula of PDF for normal distribution to get density for chi-squared then you will get a factor like this, $\frac{e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}}{x}$. And hence infinite peak at zero. Now this argument will remain unchanged whether we have a extra constant coefficient $\alpha_{i}$ in definition. Hence I have said that `qualitative characteristics will remain same'. Similar arguments can be raised for DOFs>1.

Looking forward for any comments on my answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is tempting to analyze the PDF of a random variable when trying to analyze a transformation of the random variable.  Your analysis seems to make good sense with the chi-squared distribution, but I'm afraid similar analysis with other distributions wouldn't hold.  As in my answer I posted, this modified chi-squared variables ends up being Gamma distributed, which is very similar to chi-squared.  Starting with the MGF (Moment Generating Function) is usually a great way to go.